# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express download

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

Where can I find Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express setup?

I searched a lot on the internet, but I did not find it!

I need it because I have a database already created on another laptop using Visual Studio 2008, and now I can't open it on the new laptop.

I got this error:

> Connections to SQL Server file (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express Edition 2005 to function properly

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry about the "ddddd" but stackoverflow wouldn't submit my question because it's too short! this was my solution since i dont have anything more to say!

Comment: Finding it with **Google**, you can actually still download [SQL Server 2005 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21844) from the Microsoft Download site.

Comment: marc_s 's link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21844 is now dead